# Implicit operators and a compiler error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I have a class (simplified for the purposes of this question) that wraps a `decimal` value and uses a couple of [`implicit operator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) declarations for converting between the type and the wrapped value:

```
private class DecimalWrapper
{
    public decimal Value { get; private set; }

    public DecimalWrapper(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator decimal(DecimalWrapper a)
    {
        return a != null ? a.Value : default(decimal);
    }

    public static implicit operator DecimalWrapper(decimal value)
    {
        return new DecimalWrapper(value);
    }
}
```

The usages of `implicit operator` here allow things like these to be done:

```
DecimalWrapper d1 = 5; // uses implicit operator DecimalWrapper
DecimalWrapper d2 = 10;
var result = d1 * d2; // uses implicit operator decimal

Assert.IsTrue(result.Equals(50));
Assert.IsTrue(result == 50);
```

Now, consider a second class (again, simplified) that has an overloaded constructor that can take a `decimal` or a `DecimalWrapper`:

```
private class Total
{
    private readonly DecimalWrapper _total;

    public Total(DecimalWrapper total)
    {
        _total = total;
    }

    public Total(decimal totalValue)
    {
        _total = totalValue;
    }
}
```

I would expect to be able to instantiate an instance of `Total` by passing in an integer value, which would get converted to a decimal:

```
var total = new Total(5);
```

However, this results in a compiler error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Namespace.Total.Total(TypeTests.DecimalWrapper)' and 'Namespace.Total.Total(decimal)'

To fix this, you have to remove the `implicit operator decimal` or specify that the value `5` is in fact a `decimal`:

```
var total = new Total(5m);
```

This is all well and good, but I don't see why the `implicit operator decimal` is relevant here. So, what is going on?

Comment: "does not even get executed when this runs" --- why should it? You have passed a decimal, so no cast needed - the `Total(decimal totalValue)` constructor exactly matches it.

Comment: @zerkms - I've clarified my question a little

Comment: It is relevant because there is `Total(DecimalWrapper total)` constructor and an implicit conversion `int -> decimal -> DecimalWrapper`. Compiler (after it could not find the exact signature match) checks what constructors it can fulfill after type conversion, and in this case it's both.

Comment: You've got implicit operators because you want to avoid situations like multiple constructors: why not just remove the one that explicitly takes a `DecimalWrapper`?

Comment: Btw, relevant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(v=vs.71).aspx (in the newer downloadable standard version it has more thorough description, but even by that link it's fine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a citation from the language specification?

The cause of this has to do with overload resolution. When you specify an `int` value as the constructor parameter, no overload is considered "best" because both require a conversion. The specification doesn't consider two levels of conversion different from one level, so the two constructor overloads are equivalent to each other.

As [Blorgbeard noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600029/implicit-operators-and-a-compiler-error#comment68435857_40600029), you can easily resolve the issue by getting rid of one of the constructors. He suggests removing the `DecimalWrapper` overload, but since your field is of the `DecimalWrapper` type, I'd get rid of the `decimal` overload instead. Doing it this way, if you specify an `int` value for the constructor, the compiler will implicitly convert to `decimal` and then `DecimalWrapper` for you. If you specify a `decimal` value for the constructor, the compiler will implicity convert to `DecimalWrapper` for that call, which is what your `decimal` constructor would have done anyway.

Of course, yet another way to address the issue would be to add other constructors to the `Total` class, e.g. one that takes an `int`. Then no conversion is required and the `int` constructor would be chosen. But this seems like overkill to me.